# x.ToString() or x + ""?

Tags: c#

This question maybe looks stupid and/or out of the topic, but it's very interesting for me.

In C# imagine that you have a variable named as `x` and its type **is not important** (type of `x` maybe is `int`, `char`, `long` or something else...). For this `x` which *operation* faster than another; `x.ToString();` or `x + "";` ?

I don't know which is faster, but I think that *in astronomic iterations* `x + ""` should be faster. But according to the logic `x.ToString()` method should be faster.

I know that C# is high level programming language. That's why C# *gone away* from machine language. Thus, execution time slowing down.

If somebody tested this, please tell me which method and why faster than another one.

Comment: i have not tested it, but i guess .ToString() should be faster, if there is any difference at all, since this operation requires a string-conversion. i have not tested it mysel, but i am sure you could easily do it your self (you even explained it)

Comment: `x+""` is null-safe, while `x.ToString()` is not.

Comment: "I think that in astronomic iterations x + "" should be faster" - why?

Comment: [If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: [Fastest Way to Convert an Int to a String](http://cc.davelozinski.com/c-sharp/fastest-way-to-convert-an-int-to-string)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight `x?.ToString()`.

Comment: @UweKeim that would prevent `NullReferenceException` from being thrown, but the result would be different: `+ ""` returns empty string for `null`, while `?.ToString()` would return `null`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you compile your `x + ""` code and than decompile it back or look into IL, you'll notice that compiler replaces it with `string.Concat` call:

```
x1 = input + "";
```

becomes

```
x1 = string.Concat(input);
```

And if you [look at what `string.Concat` does](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,a17e32697e4baaf6) you'll see that it indeed does call `ToString`, but it also makes additional `null` check on the input:

```
public static String Concat(Object arg0) {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<String>() != null);
    Contract.EndContractBlock();

    if (arg0 == null)
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
    return arg0.ToString();
}
```

So, as you can see it's more code to exeucte than just `ToString` call, which means it can't be faster than just `ToString` call.

They might be really close if JIT is able to optimize the null check away in some cases, but in general `+ ""` will be slower than `ToString` call.

But you should also be aware that the two do not have exactly the same behavior: `ToString` on `null` will throw `NullReferenceException`, while `+ ""` will return an empty string.

Comment: that's what I need! Thanks very much!!